# Binary Search creates infinte loop only when the search item is an even number

Tags: java, infinite-loop, binary-search

For my class I need to make a program that uses both a binary search and linear search. The linear search works fine, so I know that the problem isn't that the desired search term doesn't exist.

I tried to find an answer, but this appears to be a very unique problem.

I am reading a book list from a file and placing it into an array in a custom Books class that stores the title and ID number. I am searching by the ID number, and whenever the Id number is an odd number, it works fine; if it is an even number it creates an infinite loop.

This is the code in question.

```
private String binarySearch(String indexNumber){

    int left, middle, right, compare;
    String book = null;
    Boolean found = false;

    left = 0;
    right = list.length -1;

    while (found == false) {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        compare = list[middle].index.compareTo(indexNumber);

        if (compare == 0) {
            book = list[middle].title;
            found = true;
        } else {
            if (compare > 0) {
                right = middle - 1;
                System.out.println("New Right: " + right);
            } else {
                left = middle + 1;
                System.out.println("New Left: " + left);
            }
        }
    }
    return book;
}
```

EDIT:
Revised code

```
private String binarySearch(String indexNumber){
    int left, middle, right, compare;
    String book = null;
    left = 0;
    right = list.length -1;

    while (left <= right) {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;

        compare = list[middle].index.compareTo(indexNumber);

        if (compare == 0) {
            book = list[middle].title.toString();
            break; //tried a return here and same problem as described below
        } else {
            if (compare > 0) {
                right = middle - 1;
            } else {
                left = middle + 1;
            }
        }

    }
    return book;
}
```

This fixed the infinite loop, but it still only returns the null book value from before the loop (but only on even numbers, odd numbers still display properly), even if I put the return statement where the break is currently.

Comment: Currently you don't have *any* way of exiting the loop until you've found something. What do you want to happen if you end up without finding a result? (Hint: compare left and right in your loop condition. Get rid of `found`  and `book` and just return as soon as you *do* find something.)

Comment: BTW `middle = (left + right) / 2` can overflow. You can use `middle = (left + right) >>> 1;` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your binary search is that it insists on finding a match; otherwise, it does not exit at all.

To fix this problem replace `found == false` condition with `left <= right`:

```
while (left <= right) {
    ...
    if (compare == 0) {
        book = list[middle].title;
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That fixed the infinite loop, but now for some reason it wont return my new book value, but rather the null book value from before the while loop.

Comment: @MRoffel Try replacing `compare > 0` with `compare < 0`. It looks like your code goes left when the search value is on the right.

Comment: I tried and that must not be it, because it will still return properly when the index is an odd number and doesn't do anything at all when I changed it

Comment: @MRoffel Just to make sure: `list` is sorted on `list[i].index` in ascending order, right?

Comment: I never explicitly sorted it, now that I look at it, but the text file I am reading it from is in order by index.